# DSL problem in ubuntu 15.04

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, dsl

Network is not connecting,
I get the error message

```
(1) Creating object for path '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActivationConnection/4' failed in libnm-glib.
```

Comment: Did your problem solved with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem in `ubuntu 15.04` dsl connection.

One solution is to re-install the `pppoe` package as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install pppoe
```

And choose `default`.

Let me know if this solution not solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. What fixed it for me was removing and re-installing NetworkManager as described in [this Ubuntu forums post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2239214&s=c6ab3f348f704949b982b2f10042556c&p=13096999#post13096999).

```
sudo apt-get install -d --reinstall network-manager network-manager-gnome  
sudo apt-get purge network-manager network-manager-gnome
```

Reboot.

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome
```

You will of course require an internet connection for this. For me rebooting temporarily solved the issue (long enough for me to complete the reinstallation) or you could try using an ethernet connect or copying the packages from another computer.